# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular 6.0 SPA template - razor page (cshtml) for index instead static page

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am trying to migrate my `ASP.NET Core 2.0 Angular 5` application with `webpack` setup to `ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular 6` with `Angular-Cli`.

**Short question:**

How can I force parsing razor pages directives from `cshtml` with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`?

I do not want to use `index.html` from `Angular.json`, but `index.cshtml`.

**Long description:**

I started a new ASP.NET Core project from [Angular template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio). There are quite a few things that just magically works.

1. There is an `index.html` file inside `ClientApp/src` folder which is
   automatically served when application starts.
2. When application runs, before `</body>` tag from `index.html` (from first point) several scripts are inserted: `inline.bundle.js`, `polyfills.bundle.js`, `vendor.bundle.js`, `main.bundle.js` and `styles.bundle.css` before `</head>` tag.

I am not sure who inserted those scripts, but I want to insert them to Razor page (`cshtml`).

I tried to use code from my old project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
@{string googleAnalyticsId = Html.Raw(ViewData["GoogleAnalyticsId"]).ToString();}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleAnalyticsId))
{
    <script>
        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m)
        {
           ...
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', '@googleAnalyticsId', 'auto');
    </script>
}
<script>
    @Html.Raw(ViewData["TransferData"])
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css" async defer />
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<app>
    <!-- loading layout replaced by app after startupp -->
    <div class="page-loading">
        <div class="bar">
            <i class="sphere"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</app>
</body>
</html>
```

And point index options in `Angular.json` to this `index.cshtml`:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot/dist",
            "index": "Views/Home/Index.cshtml",   //<----- here
```

Problem is that content (all @ tags) is not processed by ASP.NET Core but it outputs direct content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
@{string googleAnalyticsId = Html.Raw(ViewData["GoogleAnalyticsId"]).ToString();}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(googleAnalyticsId))
{
    <script>
...
```

but it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Test title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
```

I want to print some variables (from appsettings.json) to the end html page. Since I am already using ASP.NET Core, Razor page seems good solution.

**I also try:**
to add new RazorPage, C# content (@ directives) are processed, but no-one is inserting Angular scripts.

**Response for AndyCunningham answer:**

`ng build --prod` writes this files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.b38c91f828237d6db7f0.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2fc3e5708eb8f0eafa68.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.16911708c355ee56ac06.js"></script>
```

to `index.html`. How to write this to razor page.

Comment: i am facing the same issue as new template do not have Index.cshtml. Is your issue resovled?If yes, can you please share the snipet ?

Comment: Hi @SagarK I needed to write some data from database so I wanted to use Razor pages. Currently, I am editing static Index.html page on Startup.

Comment: ok but how you configured authentication in Start up as there is no use of MapSpaFallbackRoute

Comment: This is such a trivial problem and I'm shocked that there's no support of this. I would think that this would be a desired feature for SEO. Overall, it seems like whoever made this system, and maybe I'm overlooking other reasons, didn't know about the Single Responsibility Principle... Did you guys ever figure anything out for this?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 6):

I'm basing this answer on my experience with React SPA extensions, but it should be helpful for Angular as well, as it uses [the same `ClientApp/index.html` middleware mechanism](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs), and the same [`IApplicationBuilder.UseSpa`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L29) entrypoint.

The problem is that when you use `app.UseSpa(...)`, the default implementation of this extension [configures](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L43) [a middleware that listens for ALL UI requests and fwds them to index.html](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.cs#L23).

I've built a quick example of how we get around this for our projects: https://github.com/andycmaj/aspnet_spa_without_indexhtml/pull/1/files should show you what needs to change in order to ignore index.html and use a razor view instead.

Basically, i've re-implemented what `UseSpa` does, but without attaching the middleware that intercepts and fwds to index.html.

Note that the `Home` razor view still needs to do the more important things that index.html was doing. Most importantly, it needs to [include `bundle.js`](https://github.com/andycmaj/aspnet_spa_without_indexhtml/blob/razor-home/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L18) served by the SPA static content middleware.

Comment: This looks promising. Can you please explain how is this different then Eliseo solution? It still missing all scripts, which file names are created dynamically.

Comment: @Makla scripts are all served from `static/js` so the [`IsSpaRoute` matcher](https://github.com/andycmaj/aspnet_spa_without_indexhtml/pull/1/files#diff-44faab4f65e309f07f97a11f35f4a1d0R75) maps all scripts to the static content server. It's different in that it still leverages the SpaExtensions's `IOptions` and [`SpaBuilder`](https://github.com/andycmaj/aspnet_spa_without_indexhtml/pull/1/files#diff-44faab4f65e309f07f97a11f35f4a1d0R93) so you don't have to figure out how to serve those files yourself. You just have to map their middleware to specific Spa file paths.

Comment: @AndyCunnigham I don't understand how to write scripts tags to razor page (since they are dynamic). Can you please check my question. At the bottom is section: `Response for AndyCunningham answer`.

Comment: @AndyCunningham, I think his point is the Razor file tries to get `/static/js/bundle.js` but webpack hashes the file name for cache busting, so someone has to read the file name from the original static html file.

Answer (score 5):

it's and old question, but I hope the answer help someone

Well, is difficut make that webpack insert the scripts tag in you index.cshtml, but you can include the tags in the index.cshtml like

```
@{
    ViewData["title"] = "I'am from cshtml";
}
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
```

then you can router your mvc like

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        template: "{*url:regex(^((?!.css|.map|.js|sockjs).)*$)}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

});
```

See that all the routes that not correcponding with {controller}{action=Index}/{id?} fall in "spa-fallback" that say that if the file not have .css or .map or .js or .sockjs serve your Home/Index. It's necesary the "regex" for .NET serve the script files necesarys.

The last step is configure your angular.json to maintaine the name of the scripts using outputHashing:all

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all", //<--add this line
                  ...
            },
            ....
  },
  "defaultProject": "ClientApp"
}
```

At last we can check if an url is valid or not (else any url server the index page) you can use in startup.cs some like

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string path = context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(1);
    bool encontrado = path.EndsWith(".js") || path.EndsWith(".css") || path.EndsWith(".map") || path.StartsWith("sockjs");
    if (!encontrado)
    {
        ..use your code to check the url...
    }
    if (encontrado)
        await next.Invoke(); //<--continue
    else
    {   //send to an error404 page
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "error404.html"));
    }
});
```

NOTE: I put the href of the scripts in absolute path, e.g src="/runtime.js", well in package json we can have several scripts like

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href=/ --serve-path=/",
    "start:fr": "ng serve --base-href=/fr-FR/ --configuration=fr --serve-path=/fr-FR",
    "build": "ng build",
    ...
  },
```

If we use --serve-path=fr-FR, the href of script must use this serve-path, e.g. src="/fr-FR/runtime.js"

Comment: This is not working for me. If I add index razor page, content is served from here when application starts, but no one includes Angular scripts.

Comment: @Makla, you are WHO has to inserted the scripts tab. See my e.g of index.cshtml at first of the answer. The idea is that you take advantage that the runtime.js, pollyfil.js..  was in server, so any .hmtl can include. Don't forget that you must maintance the UseAngularCliServer. only need replace the app.UseMvc and add the script manually in your index.cshtml

Comment: And here is the problem. There is simply to much version. This process must be automated. Thanks anyway. I can not manually adding hash to every script in production environment.

Comment: adding hash? I'am not sure understand you. if you use "outputHashing": "all" the files are always: runtime.js, polyfills.js, styles.js, vendor.js and main.js there are no hash. Anyway I'll try to make a github (but I can't promise when)

Comment: @Eliseo, I would be interested in seeing that github repo.

Answer (score -1):

You're sort of on the right path, you still need everything you have in your `_layout.cshtml` but you're not modifying Angular index.html. Instead your `Home/Index.cshtml` or `_layout.cshtml` will include the `<app-root>` element as well as all your angular scripts. You'll likely want to disable hashes from thegenerated angular files and use ASP.NET to invalidate your JS.

This link explains this in detail but I still have some minor issues with it in Angular 6 + ASP.NET Core 2.1:
[Add Angular 5 CLI project to ASP.Net Core 2.0 project](https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/add-angular-5-cli-project-to-asp-net-core-2-0-project-9223a03b7ead)