# NET Core Angular multiple themes

Tags: angular, templates, asp.net-core

Is it possible with Net Core and Angular to create different themes to be added externally?

For example: Custom themes from users, without new compiling app

or can users design "own" angular apps (own layout and style) that are loaded via Net Core

Comment: Using NET Core, Don't think it's feasible. You can try Angular Universal, which will bootstrap Angular application in Server side and Template will be generated and loaded in the front end.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya, of course it's possible (not easy). Think that you can deploy an Angular using a index.cshtml, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815456/asp-net-core-2-1-angular-6-0-spa-template-razor-page-cshtml-for-index-instea?rq=1