# Add Angular 4/6 component inside razor view (netcore mvc project)

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created 2 angular(6) components, and i want to know if it is posible to add my angular componets inside a netcore razor view

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815456/asp-net-core-2-1-angular-6-0-spa-template-razor-page-cshtml-for-index-instea ?