# .net Core : Angular SPA template update causing authentication issue

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, .net-core, openid-connect

We are using Angular 5.2 and recently updated the SPA template. Where in which :
1) New SPA template do not have index.cshtml file, now all request are getting redirected to index.html file. so my first question is :

> Can we retain razor file behavior in new template ?

2) We are using OpenIDConnect authentication like :

```
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = azureAdConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = string.Format(azureAdConfig.AADInstance, azureAdConfig.Tenant);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Resource = azureAdConfig.ResourceURI_Graph;

                // PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                options.Events = new AuthEvents(azureAdConfig, connectionStringsConfig);
            });
```

**But after updating template, first UI is getting loaded and authentication is not getting called.**

The reason being old startup.cs file has MapSpaFallbackRoute which is used to redirect to Home Index action which causing authentication to get called :

```
 routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

In New template if we set this configuration, getting following error :

**Not able to find file Views/Home/Index.cshtml**  
As new SPA template project structure do not have this file. If we remove this configuration then only UI gets loaded with no server calls.

> so second question how to retain the old behavior of authentication being called first in this new template. which configuration i am missing here ?

Comment: The SPA recipe marries a SIMPLE STATIC file server with a simple REST request handle. You CANNOT add auth to it because it is specifically designed not to allow it. Add the auth on your Web API.

Comment: You can get your old behaviour by rewriting the entire application from scratch (and in JavaScript). ASP.net SPA is not ASP.net MVC.

Comment: so how to authenticate from client side ?

Answer (score 1):

Razor is a server side rendering technology. SPA means "all rendering is done client side". So no. Razor is the opposite to SPA.

You cannot marry the technologies since they are diametrically opposite.

If you endeavour to write SPA with razor. Then you must bring the mountain to Mohammad. You MUST run the razor on the client. [There is a Microsoft beta tech called Blazor for that.](https://blazor.net)

Comment: that's not true. You can use razor too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815456/asp-net-core-2-1-angular-6-0-spa-template-razor-page-cshtml-for-index-instea/51581739 (it's a bit hard, but it's possible)

Comment: @Eliseo That isn't SPA then. Razor is a server rendering technology, therefore, dynamic pages hence MULTIPLE PAGES. Multiple Page is the opposite of SINGLE PAGE.

Comment: @Eliseo  My problem is authentication is not getting triggered. I am using OPen Id Connect authentication with Azure AD

Comment: With SPA you can't do auth on the HTML. That wouldn't be single page. You have to do your auth on the REST API part of the application. SPA means "Single Static Page + JavaScript". It's not a single page if you return 401, that would be 2 pages.