# Asp.Net Core MVC (version 2.2): add Angular 7 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web application created with asp.net core mvc (version 2.2).

Can Angular components (latest version) be added to the razor view?

I tried to create the Angular application in the same folder as the Asp.Net Core MVC project but I don't know how to call Angular in the Razor view.

Can you help me and tell me the steps to follow to make the two applications interact?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use Angular as a front-end framework and .NET Core for your back-end.

Often the back-end would just expose an API for the front-end framework as a way of getting data to the client. E.g a .NET Core API project that is ‘consumed’ by your front-end JavaScript.

You can write Angular markup into Razor views, but it will be treated as plain HTML. Angular will not compile the markup until it reaches the client, and by this time, there is no Razor syntax present, because it was all compiled to plain HTML before being sent from the server.

See comment below for an example mixing Angular markup into a pre-compiled Razor view.

Comment: Of course you can use razor and Angular. Why not?, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815456/asp-net-core-2-1-angular-6-0-spa-template-razor-page-cshtml-for-index-instea/51581739

Comment: I’ll update my answer to be more clear.  I mean you can’t have Angular interact with Razor syntax.